# SPOJ Next Palindrome: Can't figure out where why my code is getting a TLE (Time Limit Exceeded)

Tags: python, palindrome

Mentioned below is my code in Python that prints the smallest palindrome higher than K, for a given input K (K can have 10^6 digits). May not be the best of algorithms, but it works, and I have tried to use the minimum amount of resources. Not too much looping involved either (unless there's the case of all 9's). Anyhow, my code is getting TLE(Time Limit Exceeded) and I have no clue why. Could anyone kindly help me by pointing out where it might be getting too laggy? Thank you!

Code below:

```
def palin(num):
    if int(num) < 9 or int(num)%10 == 0:
        return int(num) + 1
    if int(num) == 9:
        return 11
    if int(num) >= 90 and int(num) < 99:
        return 99
    numList = []
    if len(num)%2 == 0:
        numList = list(num[:len(num)/2])
    else:
        numList = list(num[:(len(num)/2 + 1)])
    flag = 0
    carryOver = 1
    sum = 0
    i = len(numList) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        sum = (int(numList[i]) + carryOver)
        numList[i] = sum % 10
        carryOver = sum / 10
        if carryOver > 0: 
            i -= 1
        else:
            break
    if i < 0 and carryOver > 0:
            numList.insert(0,carryOver)
            flag = 1
    s = ''.join(map(str,numList))
    if flag == 1:
            if len(num)%2 == 0:
                temp = s[:-1]
                temp = temp[::-1]
                s = s[:-1] + s[-1:] + temp
                return int(s)
            else:
                temp = s[:-2]
                temp = temp[::-1]
                s = s[:-2] + s[-2:] + temp
                return int(s)
    else:
            if len(num)%2 == 0:
                temp = s[::-1]
                s = s + temp
                return int(s)
            else:
                temp = s[:-1]
                temp = temp[::-1]
                s = s[:-1] + s[-1:] + temp
                return int(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = raw_input()
    numList = []
    for i in range(int(t)):
        numList.append(raw_input())
    for i in range(int(t)):
        print palin(numList[i])
```

Comment: Temporal Lobe Epilepsy? Two-line element sets of Earth-orbiting objects? It would perhaps help if you could explain what TLEd means (I genuinely can't find anything sensible from Google) and specifically what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Time Limit Exceeded. Edited the post. It's supposed to complete in 2s - 9s in a Cube (Intel G860) processor. I thought SPOJ lingo was pretty common here. Anyhow! Temporal Lobe Epilepsy? That got me cracking!

And. There's nothing much wrong with the code. As in, it does dish out the required outputs. Problem is, I need to make it run faster and can't seem to figure out wherein it's getting laggy.

Comment: In that case, you might benefit from running [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) on your existing code. For sure that will immediately highlight the bottleneck and then you can start to focus your efforts there. At least in my case, I don't have time during the day to dig through big blocks of code like that to find the bottleneck. This approach would help you narrow down your problem.

Comment: Also, generally, this kind of question should be posted on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if it's technically functional. Whether these type of questions get answered here usually seems to depend on how interesting the problem is and how focused the question is on a specific bottleneck.